# Resolving "timestamp invalid" during ArcGIS Pro install?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, license, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-pro

Today, I downloaded and installed ESRI ArcGIS 10.3 For Desktop Advanced and then ArcGIS Pro 1.0. I assigned licenses, including a license for ArcGIS Pro, to account. I was able to authorize 10.3 and can launch that without a problem. I cannot, however, launch ArcGIS Pro. When I do, a message box appears with "timestamp invalid". No ESRI have been on this machine (clean windows install last weekend) Any thoughts about how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at your time/date setup and your regional settings (language/time/currency). It's possible that the timestamp contains 'invalid' (other than US.English) characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I performed a clean install of Windows recently and forgot to set the time zone. Upon setting the timezone, the time was off by a few hours. Once the timezone and time were set correctly, ArcGIS Pro launched as expected.

Seems like someone at ESRI could have made this message a tad more descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your computer clock is correctly synchronized with internet time. I had an error and my clock was off by a couple of minutes. Once I figured out the internet time was not synchronizing correctly and fixed it, ArcGIS worked fine.

Answer (score -4):

If you will change your organization's country on your account, the problem will be solved.